# Unsupported Media Type in jersey RESTfull api

Tags: jersey

I am trying to build a RESTfull API using the Jersey library but it gives me an exception. 
Here is my Docs class

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
public class Docs {

    @XmlElement(name = "field")
    public String field;

    @XmlValue
    public String content;

}


@Path("/update")
public class Update {
    @POST
    @Path("/xml")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String createIndexXML(Docs docs)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println(docs.content);
        return "It works";

    }

}
```

If I try to check it using CURL it throws `Error 415 Unsupported Media Type`

```xml
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:8089/update/xml" -d '<docs>
          <field>title</field>
</docs>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the content type to your request header. Add `-H "Content-Type: application/xml" to your`curl` call.

I think you're also going to find that there are problems with your annotations on your bean - but that's another issue...

Comment: I tried curl -H "Content-Type:text/xml"  -X POST "http://localhost:8089/update/xml" but still i get the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/xml"
-X POST -d "<docs><field>title</field></docs>" "http://localhost:8089/update/xml"
```

You should also try `Accept: application/xml`; watch out for defining both `@Produces` and `@Consumes`! See [Using @Consumes and @Produces to Customize Requests and Responses](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ghrpv/).